# Error while deploying an application on Openshift

Tags: mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, openshift

I have not deployed on jboss application server before. I have the following errors while trying to deploy a java web application on `openshift`. I am using `Spring` and `JPA 2.0`.

My `applicationContext.xml`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" resource-ref="true" />
```

My  `standalone.xml`

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" enabled="${mysql.enabled}" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MysqlDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                      <user-name>${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_USERNAME}</user-name>
                      <password>${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD}</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

The error

```
2012/07/12 09:00:36,714 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: tentacleSpotPU
   ...]
2012/07/12 09:00:37,118 WARN  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
2012/07/12 09:00:37,139 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: tentacleSpotPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
   at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
   at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
   at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:97)
 at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
   at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
   ... 9 more

2012/07/12 09:00:37,309 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started (with errors) in 75169ms - Started 401 of 720 services (203 services failed or missing dependencies, 113 services are passive or on-demand)
2012/07/12 09:00:37,440 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU\": Failed to start service"}}
2012/07/12 09:00:38,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 1131ms
2012/07/12 09:00:38,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU": Failed to start service

2012/07/12 09:00:38,609 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#tentacleSpotPU\": Failed to start service"}}}}
```

What do i need to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How is your project setup? Does the project run locally with jboss 7.1.0 Final?  I use a persistence.xml file that defines my EntityManagerFactory and hibernate.dialect for my JPA 2.0 configurations. Located in my META-INF directory. That is the way I have it setup in my project.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="userpersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    </provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acctdatabase"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="acct-user"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: It's deployed on Openshit https://openshift.redhat.com. And i use `Spring` to manage my persistence. So i am no doing my database connection in my `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set hibernate.dialect property to allow JBoss to load the persistence context without connection (it can use the connection to detect the dialect).  It will wait to get a connection from the application (in your case Spring).

You can set it in the persistence.xml or is should be possible in a hibernate.properties placed in a root directory of the classpath

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception. After 3-4 days I realized that the location of my persistance.xml was not correct. I have EAR Web Application that uses EJB, JSF, MAVEN, MYSQL. So, in my eclipse, I have ejb project, web project, ear project, and main project. I was updating persistance.xml file which is inside the META-INF folder under EJB project. However, I forgot to update the same thing in Web Project undre JPA Content. So, you will find the same persistance.xml file under META-INF folder in your web project. By default, unit-name will be the 'project-name-web" and class. So, update that one with respect to the same that you mentioned here, including jta-datasource to properties. It should work. 
Mine is working. Finally. Phew!